# Highlighting selected elements in angular *ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to highlight and keep the selected element active by applying a border class in my angular 2 application.But on selecting the child element under any year selects all its corresponding child components of other years.
I wanted to highlight only the selected element.

Please find the plunker link  [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3YVBOMjJPDOUaPw39nFZ?p=preview)

Code used to highlight selected element:

```
this.setClickedRow = function(index){
         console.log(index);
            this.selectedRow = index;
        }
```

Note:On hover I'm applying class `item-hover` that is working fine for individual child elements.

Please let me know if anyone has faced similar issue like this before..

Comment: You have to set the flag on the row, see [this fixed plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/egvZafU7ZtcI5lKISgbN?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your template to this:

```
<div class="border-box">
    <div  *ngFor="let item of quarterDataList">
      <h2>{{item.year}}</h2>
      <div class="item-hover" *ngFor="let count of item.quarterData;let i = index" (click)="setClickedRow((i+'_'+item.year))" [class.active]="((i+'_'+item.year)) == selectedRow">
        <br>
       {{count.view}}-{{count.count}}
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav.How can I remove the selected border if I clicked outside the panel?

Comment: @forgottofly you want to remove all the selected borders if clicked outside the <div calss "border-box"> ?

Comment: Correct @Gaurav

Comment: @forgottofly https://plnkr.co/edit/StuvlPSUYEWnIZhdueCy?p=preview, you have to click below the div to see its working not on side because this div has full width you have to minimize the width of the div for it.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav. That really helped

Comment: @forgottofly glad to help :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151483/discussion-between-forgottofly-and-gaurav-srivastava).

Answer (score 1):

Hi I fixed it in a new plunker here ->

https://plnkr.co/edit/Cys2iGOQxWGta3KjRL9f?p=preview

The key is to map your array to a selected attribute and use the view based on that.

```
this.quarterDataList.map(quarter =>{
      quarter.selected=false;
      return quarter;
})
```

And on the html

```
<div class="item-hover" *ngFor="let count of item.quarterData;let i = index" (click)="count.selected=!count.selected" [class.active]="count.selected">
```